# iOS 5 requires ARC bridged cast

Tags: ios, xcode, image, automatic-ref-counting

Im following a tutorial and I'm not sure how to convert this code to get it to run free without errors with ARC enabled.

```
- (void)setHourHandImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
if (image == NULL) {
    hourHand.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    hourHand.cornerRadius = 3;
}else{
    hourHand.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    hourHand.cornerRadius = 0.0;

}
hourHand.contents = (id)image;
```

The only part that is giving me an error is the (id)image;

Also

```
w = CGImageGetWidth((CGImageRef)hourHand.contents);
```

(CGImageRef)minHand.contents); gives me an error

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a `__bridge` cast.

```
hourHand.contents = (__bridge id)image;
```

and

```
w = CGImageGetWidth((__bridge CGImageRef)hourHand.contents);
```

The `__bridge` cast tells ARC that this cast doesn't affect the ownership of the object in any way. The alternatives are `__bridge_retained` and `__bridge_transfer`, which are generally used via the `CFBridgingRetain()` and `CFBridgingRelease()` functions.

Comment: I usually get confused a little bit with bridge since im not sure who should be in charge of releasing. Do you know how to tell if i should pass or not the ownership? (to know if i have to cfrelease the source or just pass the ownership so that arc releases it)

Comment: @LuisOscar: In general, all existing instances where you're casting to/from a CF type for a once-off (i.e. you aren't calling `CFRelease()` on the resulting `CFTypeRef`, etc.), you want `__bridge`. `CFBridgingRetain()` is the equivalent of a `CFRetain()`, i.e. it needs to be balanced with a `CFRelease()`. and `CFBridgingRelease()` balances out a `CFRetain()`/alloc/copy (by virtue of handing ownership to ARC on the resulting obj-c object).